# How to store reference to function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given a list of functions, I wish the user to be able to select any of the functions to run at startup.  How can this be done so that the user can "save" their choice of function to run the next time the code is run ie what would function runSelectedFunction (below) look like since you can't "save" a javascript function to file?  Also, assume the list of potential functions is extensible.

```js
const first = ()=>{
 console.log('first');
}

const second = ()=>{
 console.log('second');
}

const third = ()=>{
 console.log('third');
}

loadUserSelectedFunctionFromDB()
.then(runSelectedFunction)
```

To be clear, the goal is to persist the user choice even if the code stops executing and is restarted.  Normally, this would be done by storing a value in a database but the question is how to store a reference to a function in a database given an extensible set of functions?

Comment: `I wish the user to be able to select any of the functions` how will the user do this in node.js?

Comment: Assume there is a user interface that allows this

Comment: Fair enough - in that case, you use this assumed interface to do so

Comment: But that is the crux of the problem.  Let's say the user selects "Function first" and I store something in the database to reference this, say {selected function: 1}.  If I read this from the database, how do I connect the reference to the actual function.  Assume that there is an endless number of functions that can be added by other modules so I can't just create a table or if-then statement since the list of functions is unknown at designtime

Comment: Basically, in your user interface, there should be an onclick function (or select or....) the user triggers that does what you want... Your question is way too broad...

Comment: Please be advised, that this is not a homework production site. It is expected to tell what you have already tried, and in how far it didn't work, then ask a detailed question. Just dumping your questionnaire and asking others to fill it out for you is considered rude.

Comment: Navin is your response meant for this question? I am not sure it pertains as there is no questionnaire neither is there any indication that this is an academic assignment. It really is a genuine issue in a production scenario and I would appreciate pointers to a solution from anyone with better insight than I have

Comment: Are these functions not stored in the javascript file?  You expect the execution of the code to be stored in the database?

Comment: Please show your attempt at achieving your goal, and indicate any issues you have with your code - otherwise it looks like you want someone to write all the code for you, while that may be *handy* for you and your production site, it's not how stackoverflow works - without more info (i.e this assumed user interface that allows this that presumably is already in place) it's hard to help

Comment: Bravo, I have no idea how to solve this problem.  I would imagine SO also exists to also address situations where the OP is stumped.  I do have a history of contributions to SO so it should not be a stretch to imagine that I am not just trying to skive off the efforts of others.

Comment: magneticmagnum: the issue is how to persist the user choice between successive executions of the code.  Normally, I would just save the user option in a database but if the code is restarted, how do you maintain the reference to a specific function

Comment: Well, I'm probably stupid - because I can't figure out how to answer without knowing what the `assumed used interface` looks like

Answer (score 1):

Use a map like this:

```
const m = {
  first, second, third
};

let selectFuncName = "first"; // from user selection, maybe click a button
let selectFunc = m[selectFuncName];

loadUserSelectedFunctionFromDB()
.then(runSelectedFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks but I suspect I may not have been clear in my question.  The goal is to have the selected function run the next time the code is run ie step 1: run the code; step 2: user selects the function to run at startup; step 3: halt execution of the code; step 4: restart the code; step 5: selected function should then run